# New Error in Strongly-Typed View - Cannot Enumerate Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC2, having recently moved from version 1.0.

I have noticed that some of my views no longer work.  I have views that inherit from a strongly-typed `IEnumerable`, like this:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.MyType>>"
```

In the past, I have enumerated the model in my view like this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
```

But that no longer works.  I get an error in the browser:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' 
does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

I can fix it by performing the requisite casts:

```
<% foreach (MyType item in (IEnumerable<MyType>)Model) { %>
```

But this is pretty ugly, and it suggests that there has been a change in behavior, so I need to know why.

I checked, and `ViewPage.Model` is indeed defined as `object`, so I'm wondering how this could have ever worked the way it did before.  It's also defined as `object` in ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

What gives?

Note: I have the MVC source code loaded into my project.  Would that make a difference?  Is there some metadata that gets injected at runtime that makes this work, which is prevented from doing so by seeing the `object` definition in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, `ViewPage.Model` is of type `TModel` in `ViewPage<TModel>`, the generic class that you're using. (In your sample code, `TModel` is `IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.MyType>`). So it shouldn't be straight `object`.

Does it make a difference if you change your `@Page` to

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MyType>>"
```

and add a

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyProject.Models" %>
```

line to the view?

Comment: Adding the line had no effect.

Comment: `ViewPage.Model` is intellisensing as `object`. So it would seem that the page is not properly picking up the `Inherits` attribute in the `Page` directive.

Comment: In fact, none of the pages are working anymore.  They are all showing ViewPage.Model as object.

Comment: I unloaded the ASP.NET MVC source projects, restored the reference to the ASP.NET 2.0 assembly in the GAC, and the problem went away.

Comment: Cool. Maybe you had an old version of the MVC source, which didn't have the generic ViewPage?

Comment: No, it's the latest and greatest RC2 for v2.  Either there is a problem with the source (which seems unlikely), or I unwittingly did something in the source that hosed the generic ViewPage class.  Oh, well.